# SUSE Enterprise Server 11 DNS Zone Resolution Issue

Tags: dns, suse

My DNS server went belly up last week so I've rebuilt it using the following tutorial [DNS Tutorial](http://www.pcc-services.com/sles/dns2.html#).

I don't know what how I have setup it up different from the last time I configured it (I did use a different tutorial but I didn't save it) but I use to be able to connect to other pcs & servers just by specifying the machine name i.e. a http connection would be `http://Machine-Name/somefolder/page.php`.

Now with my newly configured server I have connect using the following method to connect to them i.e. a http connection is now `http://Machine-Name.dnszone.name/somefolder/page.php`

Can somebody help to shed some light on this for me? I've obviously done something or not done something which I did last time and I have spent too much time trying to find where I have gone wrong now.

Comment: I understand that multicast DNS works on the same principle but does not require a server. However when I turn the DNS server off I am unable to resolve to the lengthy DNS name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling I found that if I named my DNS zone "Private" rather than "Private.lan" as the document suggests I can call each of my networked machines using there actual computer name rather than using the long name as mentioned above which I had to use when utilising the "private.lan" DNS zone.